# Android insecure bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect android mobile to one electronic device,but I want to connect it insecurely.but its giving me the error of "java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"

here is my code

package net.londatiga.android.bluetooth;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    private final UUID WELL_KNOWN_UUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,because
        // mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(WELL_KNOWN_UUID);
            tmp = device
                    .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(WELL_KNOWN_UUID);
            Object[] params = new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(1)};
            // This is the trick
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket",
                    new Class[] { int.class });
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void run() {
        // DebugLog.i(TAG, "Trying to connect...");
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        MainActivity.mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();

            boolean val=mmSocket.isConnected();
            Log.v("val", ""+val);
            // DebugLog.i(TAG, "Connection stablished");
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            // DebugLog.e(TAG, "Fail to connect!", connectException);
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                // DebugLog.e(TAG, "Fail to close connection", closeException);
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an another thread, like below, which always receives your calls and does operations. Start this thread when you start the application.

```
class AcceptThread extends
 Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;
    private boolean flag = true;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        try {
            tmp = bluetoothAdapter
                    .listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            NAME_UUID, uuid);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        serverSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run:  connection successfull");
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: " +     socket.getRemoteDevice().getName() + "  " +
                            socket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception eee) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: " + eee.getMessage());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```